# rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I'm trying to use `Travis-CI` with a new `Ruby on Rails` project I just started a few days ago. I've tried updating `Travis-CI` to update `rubygems` in `before_install` but still no luck.

```
Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

Installing nio4r 1.2.1

An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your .travis.yml:

`rvm:
  - 2.2.2`

(or whatever the latest stable is).

Comment: It says on here that 2.2.0 is the most recent verison on Travis-CI for Ruby https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby#Choosing-Rubies-that-aren%E2%80%99t-installed